# How to rescale an integer value so that it can be compared with an image matrix in im2double format

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I used this code in MATLAB:

```
I=imread('filename');
I=im2double(I);
```

Now I have to compare an integer value, say '2', with image pixel values already converted to `im2double`. How do I rescale these integer values to its `im2double` equivalent?

Comment: Why not also with `im2double`?

Answer (score 2):

`im2double` scales the image so that the dynamic range of the intensities ranges from `[0,1]`.  If you want to compare an "integer" value with the converted image, you need to be cognizant of the **type** of image that the value came from.  For example, if the `2` came from a `uint8` image, then the dynamic range of intensities for the image ranges from `[0,255]`.  Therefore, the `2` would be converted to `2/255`.   However, if the `2` came from a `uint16` image, then the dynamic range of intensities for the image ranges from `[0,65535]`, and so the `2` would be converted to `2/65535`.

As such, this question cannot be answered unless you know the image data type that `2` value originated from.  Once you know this, then you can go ahead and convert the `2` value accordingly.  You would simply divide by the maximum value the data type can hold.

Therefore, given the integer value `val`, here's a chart you can use as a guide to the right conversion factor you need:

```
Data Type   Floating-Point Equivalent
  uint8            val/255
  uint16           val/65535
  uint32           val/4294967295
```

Note that `255 --> 2^8 - 1`, `65535 --> 2^16 - 1` and `4294967295 --> 2^32 - 1`, which makes sense.  You are aware that numbers require binary digits (bits) to represent the number and the number at the end of the data types above tell you how many bits are required to do so.  Images are essentially a 2D grid of these numbers, and these are **unsigned** data types which use all of the bits to represent the integer number in comparison to **signed** data types which use the most significant bit to signify the sign of the number.